# Une nuance entre « sous ses yeux » et « sous son nez »

Tags: expressions

**À mon avis :**

« Sous tes yeux » appuie plus fortement sur le fait qu'une chose se trouve ou se produit tout près de toi.

Quant à « Sous ton nez », en plus de marquer une extrême proximité spatiale, il peut sous-entendre que quelqu'un se cache ou s'introduit quelque part sans que tu t'en rendes compte.

Est-ce que l'on ne peut utiliser qu'une des deux expressions dans chacune des trois phrases suivantes ?

> 1. Ne me dis pas que tu t'es fait voler ta voiture { **sous tes yeux** / **sous ton nez** } !
> 2. Il est toujours à la recherche de la femme de sa vie, et il se trouve qu'elle est { **sous ses yeux** / **sous son nez** } depuis le début !
> 3. Tiens, les voilà tes lunettes ! Là, { **sous tes yeux** / **sous ton nez** } sur ton bureau !

Comment: Il y a un problème avec la structure de ta phrase "il peut s'agir de manière secrète dont quelqu'un se cache ou s'introduit quelque part en trompant ta surveillance, ou sans que tu t'en rendes compte.", mais je n'arrive pas vraiment à comprendre comment tu as voulu la construire... Ce qui me perturbe c'est que je ne trouve pas ce à quoi "dont" fait référence, et je ne trouve pas le sujet de "s'introduit", peux-tu éclaircir ? :)

Comment: You saved the day, @Random! :)

Comment: @Random As for how I originally worded the sentence, what I really meant to say was "Il peut s'agir de **la** manière secrète dont quelqu'un se cache ou s'introduit quelque part ...". It seems I didn't include "la". :)

Comment: Ah ben oui... C'est fou comme un si petit mot peu rendre une phrase incompréhensible... :)

Comment: @Random Is it fine to use « Tu m'as sauvé la mise ! » to mean "You saved the day!" for your pointing out my typo? Merci.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so... "sauver la mise" is often use in situations where you have to justify on something, and someone gives you an alibi, as if your boss is about to fire you because you are 2h late at work, and a workmate says you are late because he asked you to work late last night (whereas it's not true, he just don't want you to be fired...). But I've never heard "To save the day" before, and don't find anything on it, can you extend on what it exactly means ? I only guess I helped you finding why the sentence looks wrong ? :)

Comment: @Random Hi. The "save the day" is a cliche that corresponds with "sauver la mise". So you can use "save the day" in the very context you have provided. :) Incidentally, what I meant there was: "You helped me notice the typo, so you saved the day! (laying it on a bit thick)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La vraie différence n'est pas sur une échelle de proximité.

"**Sous le/ton nez**" comme l'expression ["passer sous le nez"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passer_sous_le_nez) vient **du registre familier** alors que "**sous les/tes yeux**" vient du **registre courant** (mais pas soutenu).

Il s'agit donc de savoir comment et à qui vous souhaitez vous adresser.

(PS : à ne pas confondre avec "[Sous mes Yeux](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=131631.html)", un joli film...)

Comment: On peut ajouter que *"sous [x]on nez"* implique souvent de s'être fait avoir, alors que l'autre est neutre.

Comment: Oui et on peut noter que c'est aussi plus péjoratif que son homologue